# OKHttp3 how disable request redirection

Tags: java, http, okhttp, bad-request, unauthorized

I send request with wrong credentials using CloseableHttpClient from Apache and I get 401 what is expected, but in case of OKHttp3 I have response with code 400 and two prior requests with 401.

My client:

```
return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
            .followSslRedirects(false)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor(log::trace)
                    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS))
            .readTimeout(120, SECONDS)
            .build();
```

How I can change it?